# Problems with Ruby Arrays

Tags: ruby

I am currently writing a small ruby class that is intended to store the amount of times a randomly generated number is seen within an array, along with the value that is seen itself.

I am trying to do the following to add the value along with a default times seen as 1 to the array. The script should check to see if the value has been included within the array and if so, increment the times this value has been seen by 1

However I am recieving duplicate values, which shouldnt happen - as the code should only allow a value to be stored once and if the value is already in the memory array, increment it by one.

The code is attatched below, if anyone can suggest what I am doing wrong it would be awesome.

Cheers
Martin

```
@memory = Array.new

def store(value)

  foundflag = false
  @memory.each do |array|
    if value == array[0]

      #Incrementing value timesseen
      array[1] = array[1]+1

      #Value found, changing found flag
      foundflag = true

      #Loop break
      break
    end
  end

  if foundflag != true then
    @memory.push([value,1])
  end

end

store(5)
```

Full script (untidy!)

```
class STAT

def initialize()
  #STAT memory settings
  @memory = Array.new

  #Prediction settings
  @predictions = 0
  @sucessfulpredictions = 0
end

#STAT main functions
def store(value)

  foundflag = false
  @memory.each do |array|
    if value == array[0]

      #Incrementing value timesseen
      array[1] = array[1]+1

      #Value found, changing found flag
      foundflag = true

      #Loop break
      break
    end
  end

  if foundflag != true then
    @memory.push([value,1])
  end

end
def predict(nosimulations)

  #Generate random value less than the total memory size
  randomvalue = rand(total)+1

  count = 0
  @memory.each do |array|
    value = array[0]
    timesseen = array[1]
    if randomvalue <= count + timesseen
      puts "Predicted value #{value}"
    end
    count = count + array[1]
  end


end
def simulate(nosimulations)

  count = 1
  while count <= nosimulations
    #Generating a random number
    randomnumber = rand(100)+1
    #Storing the random number
    store(randomnumber)
    #Print simulation details#
    puts "Running simulation #{count} of #{nosimulations}"
    puts "Generated random number: #{randomnumber}"
    #Incrementing count
    count = count + 1
  end
end

#STAT technical functions
def inspect()
  #Print memory information message
  puts "Memory information:"

  @memory.each do |array|
    value = array[0]
    timesseen = array[1]
    puts "Value #{value} - times seen: #{timesseen}/#{total}"
  end
end
def total()
  total = 0
  @memory.each do |array|
    total = total + array[1]
  end
  return total
end

#STAT load/save functions
def load(filename)
  #Default engine to be loaded
  enginename = "#{filename}.stat"

  #Print checking for saved engine message
  puts "Checking for saved memory file..."

  #Checking for saved engine
  if File.exists?(enginename)
    #Print loading engine message
    puts "Loading memory..."

    @memory = Marshal.load File.read(enginename)

    #Print engine loaded message
    puts "Engine loaded"
  else
    #Print memory not found message
    puts "Cannot load memory, no memory file found"
  end
end
def save(filename)
  #Default name for engine to be saved
  enginename = "#{filename}.stat"

  #Print saving engine message
  puts "Saving memory..."

  #Saving engine to specified file
  serialized_array = Marshal.dump(@memory)
  savefile = File.new(enginename,"w") 
  savefile.write(serialized_array) 
  savefile.close

  #Print engine saved message
  puts "Memory saved"
end

end

#STAT class test software
stat = STAT.new
filename = "test"

#Load
stat.load(filename)

#Simulate
stat.simulate(1000000)

#Testing 
#stat.store(5)
#stat.store(5)

#Inspect
stat.inspect

#Predict
#stat.predict(1000000)

#Save
stat.save(filename)
```

Comment: Can you show code that demonstrates how you get duplicates? Because I can't reproduce that (and I don't see anything in your code that would cause duplicates).

Comment: Done sepp2k, if you can have a look that would be awesome

Comment: This may have been an issue with my save file and previous versions of the software - I have deleted the save file and am testing the code now and it doesnt appear to be duplicating. Will comment again when I have tested some more.

Comment: Still can't reproduce it. Here's what I've done: I commented out the calls to load and save as well as all puts statements except the ones that print the results in the end. Then I made the argument to simulate smaller (100000) because I didn't want to wait so long. I then piped the output of the script into `sort`, so that duplicate values would appear next to each other and thus be immediately visible. I've run the code several times and never got a duplicate value.

Comment: For the future it would be nice if you could produce a *minimal* code sample that demonstrates the problem. If you can't, the problem is probably not caused where you think it is.

Comment: As a sidenote: It's a terrible idea to perform output in `inspect`. It's absolutely unacceptable to have `inspect` return `nil` (or anything else that isn't a string). This will mess with many things (like for example irb).

Comment: You should use a hash for your `@memory` instead of an array. Then you just do `@memory[value] ||= 0; @memory[value] += 1` to store a value.

Comment: This issue is still occuring... I have located the issue and it resides within the save/load function - Anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong with my file load/save?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
occurrences = Hash[ my_array.group_by{ |o| o }.map{ |o,a| [o,a.length] } ]
```

to get a hash mapping each value to the number of times it occurs. To calculate it yourself:

```
occurrences = Hash.new(0)
my_array.each{ |o| occurrences[o]+=1 }
```

*See [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) if you don't know what these methods do.*

Answer (score 0):

You are working too hard. You want **to store the amount of times a randomly generated number is seen within an array, along with the value that is seen itself**.

How can Ruby help you with that? Since you are working with an array, glance through the [available methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) and yes, there it is: `count`.

```
ar = [1,2,1,3,2,4,3,2,6,7,8,7]
rn = rand(10)
ar.count(rn)
```

Comment: Not sure if this solves the OP's needs; specifically, does s/he need the counts of all items, or a specific one only? A good answer if only one is needed.

Comment: I require the ability to store the amount of times a value that is generated is seen, along with the value itself.

Comment: Oh, and over about 10 million simulations, duplication adds up in MB saved.. thats why I am using value & timesseen